# Why can't zc.buildout find pyconfig.h?

Tags: python, django, zope, buildout

I'm running zc.buildout with a simple buildout.cfg file:

```
[buildout]
parts = python

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
```

I'm getting this error message in CentOS and Ubuntu:

```
# bin/buildout 
Installing python.
Getting distribution for 'python'.
error: Setup script exited with error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
An error occurred when trying to install Python 2.5. Look above this message for any   errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing python.
  Getting distribution for 'python'.
Error: Couldn't install: Python 2.5
```

The Python development package is definitely installed.  pyconfig.h is in /usr/include/python2.7 on my Ubuntu system.  Do I need to configure buildout differently?

Comment: Why are you trying to build the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python distribution? That's what your buildout is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using zc.recipe.egg correctly without an 'egg' or 'eggs' option?  You bootstrap (I can only assume) with your system `/usr/bin/python2.7 bootstrap.py` and then you get error messages about Python 2.5?  The problem seems that buildout is trying to get a package distribution for Python 2.5, which makes no sense.

**Try adding an empty eggs= option -- that should work.**

Comment: Thanks, "eggs=" works.  I was trying to simplify the configuration but I simplified it too much.  It did seem peculiar that buildout tried to install Python 2.5 as an egg because of this omission.

Answer (score 0):

Looks weird. I'd suspect that there's more in your buildout, especially some extra required package that needs to be compiled. That's the normal case in which buildout (or rather python itself) goes looking header files.

You say that the `.h` file exists just fine in your python 2.7 directory, but it looks like buildout runs with python 2.5, which cannot use the 2.7 one.

So if you're on ubuntu you'll need to install python2.5's dev package, too.

(But your question still looks weird to me, or rather things seem to be missing).